# Android: Access SQLite Database from service

Tags: android, sqlite, service

I can access a SQLite db from activity. But if I follow the same procedure in a service its unfortunately closing.

Here is what I tried

Creating db

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("DB", MODE_MULTI_PROCESS, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLE (ROWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, VAL VARCHAR)");
```

Inserting values

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE(VAL) VALUES ('" + edVal.getText().toString() + "');";
db.execSQL(sql);
```

To retrieve data

```
Cursor c;
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT VAL FROM MYTABLE", null);
c.moveToFirst();
if(c.getCount() > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Since I am inserting data from my activity, I don't find any problem. But I want to retrieve data in a service. From a service on executing the line for creating cursor its got unfortunately closed. Can I create cursor in a service? Or else how can I read data from the db?

Comment: How are you creating the db object in the service ? Can you paste that code ?

Comment: @Ashwin I have created it and inserting values from the activity using only the above code. I am just trying to retrieve it from service

Comment: Can you paste the code from the Service where you create the db object ?

Answer (score 1):

This man Kevin is a legend: http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474750219/single-sqlite-connection. Thank you so much.

On that link he shares his ridiculously simple solution:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
private static DatabaseHelper instance;
public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getHelper(Context context)
{
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        return instance;
    }
    //Other stuff... 
}
```

Then in your SQLite class change your code to look like this:

```
public BlacklistWordDataSource(Context context) {
dbHelper = MySQLiteHelper.getHelper(context);
}
```